# How can I stack my Gems on Steam?

Tags: steam

I have six (!) different piles of Gems, all marked with the same tags (Common, Steam, Holiday Sale 2014, Gems, Tradable, Not Marketable). Why are my Gems not stacked and how can I make them so?

[image]

Comment: God i want an answer for this one. It irritates me so much for some reason...

Comment: I deleted my previous answer. It seems items are tagged 'Not Tradable' if they have been recently bought are _yet to be_ Tradable & Marketable, as seen in the following picture: http://i.stack.imgur.com/IeQBO.png This means this can't be the problem.

Comment: I've had pretty much an entire page of gem stacks before. It's pretty terrible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**TL;DR You can stack them. Trade them all to a friend and ask them to trade it back to you.**

Hey there, sorry for the necroposting!
I found this thread by searching this same issue on Google and just figured out the solution to it.

You can actually combine those separate gems by trading them to a friend you trust and then ask them to trade it back to you. By doing so, all the gems will combine into a single gem stack, instead of 6 separate ones like you mentioned.

Hope this helps anyone in the future who face this issue!

Comment: Necroposting is not something we care about on stackexchange. As long as your answer is well researched and follows the rules, you can answer decades old questions.

Answer (score 6):

**Unfortunately, there's no way to stack them.**

Multiple groups are created when one converts an item which is not currently available for trading into gems. Trade limitations in this situation are usually from buying the items you want to convert on the market. This makes them gain the same time limitation, and causes them to be made into a separate group from the gems which are currently tradeable. However, each different "available for trade" time will create a separate stack, and once the gems become available to trade, they won't automatically restack into one group. Worse, there's also no way to do it manually.

**The only way to prevent multiple stacks of gems from occurring is to only convert items which are already available for trade into gems.**

Personally, I do all my gem conversions by opening a random market page and clicking the "Sell" button to view only those items in my inventory which can currently be traded, then converting the items there. It's inconvenient, but effective for avoiding multiple gem stacks.

Comment: Well, let's hope that Valve will fix this soon.